# Why is my Qt signal/slot breakpoint not hit? (signals/slots)

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt4.8

Ok I have Qt-Creator running my app in debug mode.
I am able to stop at SOME breakpoints; however, the code I really want to debug is invoked via the signal/slot mechanism as follows:

```
connect(saveFileButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(saveParameters()));
```

I set a few breakpoints in saveParameters() and the breakpoints are never hit.

How can I verify that the saveParameters slot is actually connected to the saveFileButton clicked signal at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[connect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connect) returns boolean value `true` if connection was successful.
In addition if connection failed in Qt Creator console you should see a log that there was such error.
You can also add `qDebug("Something")` inside `saveFileButton` if you have any doubt that debugger works properly.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the application, read the application output. If the connection cannot be made, there will be an error message like this one:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot MainWindow::saveParameters() in ../test/mainwindow.cpp:39
```